# form validation in angular 1.2

Tags: angularjs, haml

I am trying to add custom form validation to an angular app, which made in angular 1.2. I am really new to angular, and I got kind of confuse. on the front end side this app use haml and the pass field is like this :

```
        .col-lg-12.form-group{ 'data-ng-class'=>"{ 'has-error' : registration_form.password.$invalid && registration_form.password.$dirty }"}
      %input.form-control.square-borders.background-gray-fa{ :name=>"password", :placeholder=>"Password", :type=>"password", 'data-ng-model'=>"user.password", 'data-ng-focus'=> true, :required=> true,:uppercase=> true,  'data-ng-minlength'=>"6", 'data-ng-maxlength'=>"128" }
      %label{'data-ng-show'=>"registration_form.password.$invalid &&(!registration_form.password.$pristine ) && registration_form.password.$error.required && !registration_form.password.$focused", :class=>"help-block help-error-message-infield error-msg-right-correction square-borders"}
        Required
      %label{ 'data-ng-show'=>"registration_form.password.$invalid &&(!registration_form.password.$pristine ) && registration_form.password.$error.minlength && !registration_form.password.$focused", :class=>"help-block help-error-message-infield error-msg-right-correction square-borders"}
        Too Short
```

It only check the min char that is already built in in angular I want to add another restriction like this:

```
%label{ 'data-ng-show'=>"registration_form.password.$invalid &&(!registration_form.password.$pristine ) && registration_form.password.$error.uppercase && !registration_form.password.$focused", :class=>"help-block help-error-message-infield error-msg-right-correction square-borders"}
        needs at least one uppercase letter
```

what is the best approach to do this?

Comment: The best approach is to migrate to the latest stable version (1.6.4), and then read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

Comment: The problem is it's part of a big app that I have no control on, so I can't upgrade it.

Comment: Then read the same documentation for your version of angular.

Comment: I already checked the documentation, couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: I just gave you the link. Just change the version, and you'll have documentation, with a complete example. https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.32/docs/guide/forms#custom-validation